# ATOMS Arduino for scilab

Tags: arduino, scilab

I am trying to install the arduino toolbox on my 
windows 64. I use Scilab 5.5.2. 
Usually to install I select the "box" atoms in scilab but the box
does not show the arduino toolbox in the list of toolboxes.

I downloaded the file "arduino_1.1-1.bin.x64.windows.zip" and unzipped but after that I do not know what to do to install the tool box and follow the examples.

I really need to use Scicos to monitor sensors through arduino thus the installation of toolbox is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Install Scilab 5.4.1. It contains an Arduino tool box.

The same thing happens with me with Scilab 5.5.2 but it happens only occasionally with some computers.  The reason is also unclear to me, but for the time being, uninstall 5.5.2 and use Scilab 5.4.1.

Comment: Your caps lock key appears to have been stuck.  Please fix that before posting again.  Thanks.